# Where did ListenableFuture vanish to?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, admob, google-play-services

My app suddenly doesn't build anymore with this error:

> error: package com.google.common.util.concurrent does not exist

> import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

Why all of the sudden? This was working fine for quite some time. All libraries are up to date. What do I need to do for this to compile again?

**Update:** this is happening after upgrading

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.3.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.4.0'
```

going back to version 22.3.0 and everything is fine. Is this a bug in the ads library? Some weird version mixup of different library versions, maybe with room or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be intentional on Google's part. I've taken a look at the maven repository [page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads/22.4.0) for the artifact for both the `22.3.0` version and `22.4.0`, and the latter has a compile dependency on listenablefuture that is 'empty to avoid conflict with Guava`. It looks a little bit ambiguous so here is what the dependency says in its description (again, this dependency does NOT exist in 22.3.0):

> An empty artifact that Guava depends on to signal that it is providing ListenableFuture -- but is also available in a second "version" that contains com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture class, without any other Guava classes. The idea is: - If users want only ListenableFuture, they depend on listenablefuture-1.0. - If users want all of Guava, they depend on guava, which, as of Guava 27.0, depends on listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava. The ...

This was taken from [here ListenableFuture empty dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/listenablefuture).

Ideally, if you want to use ListenableFuture, you would declare the Guava dependency but if you only need `ListenableFuture`, you may depend on the aforementioned artifact instead, as it seems to do the job. This is it:

`implementation("com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0")`

Answer (score 0):

You could add an explicit dependency if you need `ListenableFuture`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/background/asynchronous/listenablefuture

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-android"

    // To use CallbackToFutureAdapter
    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava:1.6.0"
}
```

Comment: ```implementation 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures-ktx:1.1.0'``` was enough for me to use ListenableFuture